# Node.js http basic auth

Tags: javascript, authentication, ubuntu, node.js, basic-authentication

Is it possible to do basic auth in Node.js just like in Apache?

http://doc.norang.ca/apache-basic-auth.html

I know that if using Express or Connect I can add  middle-ware functionality and do user verification, but I'm trying to restrict the whole area (I don't need to authenticate users from a database just a couple of defined users) - I'm using Ubuntu.

https://github.com/kaero/node-http-digest

That's something I can do, but I'm not sure if "exposing" or directly writing the user and password in the code is secure enough.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Passport](http://passportjs.org/) provides a clean mechanism to implement basic auth.  I use it in my Node.js Express app to protect both my Angularjs-based UI as well as my RESTful API.  To get passport up and running in your app do the following:

- npm install passport
- npm install passport-http (contains "BasicStrategy" object for basic auth)
- Open up your app.js and add the following:

  ```
  var passport = require('passport')    
  var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy

  passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
      if (username.valueOf() === 'yourusername' &&
        password.valueOf() === 'yourpassword')
        return done(null, true);
      else
        return done(null, false);
    }
  ));

  // Express-specific configuration section
  // *IMPORTANT*
  //   Note the order of WHERE passport is initialized
  //   in the configure section--it will throw an error
  //   if app.use(passport.initialize()) is called after
  //   app.use(app.router) 
  app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret:'123abc',key:'express.sid'}));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.set('view options', {
      layout: false
    });
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(logger);
  });

  // Routes

  app.get('/', passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }), routes.index);
  app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);

  // JSON API

  app.get('/api/posts', passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }), api.posts);
  app.get('/api/post/:id', passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }), api.post)
  // --Repeat for every API call you want to protect with basic auth--

  app.get('*', passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }), routes.index);
  ```

Answer (score 13):

Put this

```
app.use(express.basicAuth(function(user, pass) {
  return user === 'test' && pass === 'test';
}));
```

before the line to

```
app.use(app.router);
```

to protect all routes with http basic auth

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at: 
[user authentication libraries for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498005/user-authentication-libraries-for-node-js/4975745#4975745)

It does not answer your question 100% - but maybe it helps.

Comment: Hi @nivoc, thanks for replying, yeah probably middle-ware is the way to go, I have not seen any other solution for this case scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I think good choice could be [http-auth](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth) module

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Application setup.
var app = express();
app.use(auth.connect(basic));

// Setup route.
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send("Hello from express - " + req.user + "!");
});
```

Comment: I think a disclaimer that you are the maintainer of `http-auth` would be appropriate here.