# Skip basicAuth for one route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-authentication, node.js-connect

I'm using node, express and connect for a simple app and have basic HTTP auth implemented as follows (lots of code left out for brevity):

```
var express = require('express'),
connect = require('connect');

app.configure = function(){
  // other stuff...
  app.use(connect.basicAuth('username', 'password'));
  // other stuff...
};
```

I've tried googling and even attempted implementing my own auth, but I can't figure out how to skip this auth for just one route.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone offer any help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use authentication for all routes, you should add the auth function as middleware to each individual route like so:

```
app.get('/mysecretpage', basicAuth, function (req, res) {
  console.log('you have to be auth to see this page');
});
```

Here is a regular route without auth:

```
app.get('/sample', function (req, res) {
  console.log('everybody see this page');
});
```

This link may be useful for you also: [how to implement login auth in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990890/how-to-implement-login-auth-in-node-js/8003291#8003291)

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm playing with this but how would I implement the auth in my middleware function? The page you linked to shows a check for a user session but I just want basic HTTP auth to happen in there. Here's what I have: `basicAuth = function(req, res, next) {
  if (settings.auth.enabled) {
    connect.basicAuth(settings.auth.user, settings.auth.pass);
    next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
};`

Comment: Like this: app.get('/secret', connect.basicAuth('username', 'password'), function (req, res) { ... });