# authentication system with node.js restify and backbone.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I have challenged myself, I would like to write an authentication system with restify(node.js) and backbone.js.

My questions is, could somebody give me some tips, about security or which middleware I have to use for example.

Comment: check out http://passportjs.org/

Comment: yes i will check. What should i choose, expressjs or restify?

Comment: I've never used restify, so I can't say. Whatever you choose though, you might look to passport for inspiration on how to proceed.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/halrobertson/test-restify-passport-facebook) is a GH project that ties Restify and Passport together. The example uses FB authentication with Passport, but you can replace the FB part with any of the other authentication providers for Passport.

Comment: what you recommend to use restify or expressjs?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve. I prefer express for web site with page rendering and I used restify for hosting rest apis. If you want to write an authentication system, you should make sure to support both I think instead of choosing one. You should make sure to follow the connect middleware approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passport is a very well implemented module. Everyauth and passport are the top starred projects in github. Here is an amazing thread on stackoverflow about [both of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974947/everyauth-vs-passport-js) . Just to reiterate - Async over Promises pattern. Also I love the modularity offered by passport. Saved me tons of code and makes your code look good.

I have used passport for [facebook auth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) and implemented my own authentication using [passport local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local). My backend is mongodb and mongoose helped me a lot.

I like express better than restify. It is extremly well documented and comes with a strong community support.