# Hello.js vs Passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, hello.js

I've been wondering about this for a little bit and I've done a bit of searching, but found nothing (except for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11974947/677526), which is different). I'm attempting to clarify the differences between [Hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js/) and [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/), and figure out what the use cases are for both.

On the surface, aside from one being client-side and one being node middleware, they seem to deliever similar functionality, and they are both modular.

I've done a bit of poking around with Passport, but haven't tried Hello.js yet.

**What are the main differences between the two libraries, and what use cases would prefer one library over the other?**

Comment: @jfriend00 You sure about that? On the Hello.js page, there's a demo for multiple login services, but the login pages are provided by the OAuth providers. Hello doesn't offer browser UI, from what I can tell, and from my experience Passport will also display the vendor login screen for an OAuth or OpenID service (via a callback function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hellojs is an alternative to thirdparty SDK's like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript for example, as such its suited to the development of rich client side apps which perform various requests to a thirdparty's api on behalf of the user. 
Passport.js is designed around federated authentication, identifying a users session through a thirdparty - stackoverflow is a perfect example as it lets me sign in with my google account.

Comment: This is actually a great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, hello js is client side sdk, for most common social websites, and this is its power you can integrate hello with any website either it built in php, .net, node, java, python, etc......

Because javascript is everywhere  :)