# Securely access files or images from the backend by react

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, fetch, mern

I have a MERN app, and i'm storing files as well as images in a static folder on the backend (nodejs express).  I can fetch these files or images from react using fetch, getting a response as a blob and then displaying them as normal.  My problem is this:

I don't want clients/users to be able to access the backend file path for example http://ip:3000/{userid}/images/{imageId} because the files belong to the owner and should only be accessible to the owner.

I'm struggling to be able to have the front end access the files, and show them.  What is happening, is the browser will make the request to the backend and get the file itself. I have tried to use localhost on the front end in the fetch request, to limit it so only the front end has access, but then any testing done from another system will result in a 404 error.

So how can i accomplish this?  I am using local storage instead of something like firebase, because I want full control over where my files are stored.  But regardless of their location, how can I restrict the browser from accessing them directly and having them served by the front end so all the browser sees, is the files coming from the front end?

I tried to restrict access using CORS but it doesn't seem to work the way I expect.  The web browser still wants to access the files directly, meaning if the person has the URL, they can access any file.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't serve them statically. Set up a route to retrieve files and use `res.sendFile()` only after verifying access

Comment: Require a login, and have the user authenticate.  See [how to implement login auth in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7990890/1563833) or [NodeJS + Express: How to secure a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12276046/1563833)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Phil thank you, that was the answer I needed.