# Login system with status codes and secure redirects

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, ejs

I have a login system, node.js ofc and working with ejs, but this login system is different and can't be altered
Here's my login code

```js
// DOES A HTTP POST TO LOGIN SERVER 
if (code.data == "201") {
  let uid = req.body.uid;
  res.render('dashboard', { name, uid })
}
if (code.data == "403") {
  console.log('Invalid Creds!')
}
if (code.data == "404") {
  console.log('User not found')
}
```

Now I have a few `app.get` function that redirects to other pages from the dashboard, but here's the part where i need help, now when a user is redirected to a new page he gets redirected just fine but the issue is the person who isn't logged in also gets access!

```js
app.get('/new', (req, res) => {
  res.render('new')
})
```

Another thing, 2 things from the login are sent to the dashboard, now the same data should be sent to the next page, in our case it is a `/new`

People have asked me to use a passport system but I just couldn't get it to work

I've been trying for weeks (more than 6) but couldn't figure it out, someone please help :(

Comment: There is no user login validation is checked resulting any user getting redirected. This will be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282448/login-authentication-in-nodejs