# Authentication solutions for Node.js

Tags: authentication, node.js

Are there any robust authentication libraries for node.js as for rails (devise, sorcery), that could allow to do external authentication (facebook connect, twitter...) as well?

Comment: What kinds of external authentification?

Comment: Facebook connect, twitter, open id..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [user authentication libraries for node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498005/user-authentication-libraries-for-node-js)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) allows you to set up authentication with a wide range of services.

It basically gives you an API to map facebook or twitter or google authentication objects to your user models and back again.

Some examples of it being used:

- [my blog](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog/blob/master/src/init/everyauth.js)
- [everyauth example file](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/blob/master/example/server.js)
- [my chat application](https://github.com/Raynos/so642/blob/master/src/init/config-everyauth.js)

Comment: Thank you, i'm already reading about everyauth =)

Answer (score 18):

[Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) supports more than 30 authentication strategies.